# Rails/Devise - What should I test with devise and rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot

Many programmers use devise as their authentication solution and I would like to get their advice:

Devise is already tested, but I want to know if there is something to test by myself (integration/unit/funtionnal tests?) for a standard devise integration with my knowledge 
(I'm not familiar with shoulda and cucumber, but I know a bit of rspec and factory girls)

Thanks for your advices!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing the integration can be great. Because is how you integrate devise where you can do some error. Define some cucumber feature and it's OK.

Answer (score 6):

From the unit testing perspective, devise provides 2 helper methods

```
sign_in @user          # sign_in(resource)
sign_out @user         # sign_out(resource)
```

You might be needing them to test if your controller actions are behaving in a proper way such as not allowing you to create a post when you are not logged in.

From the Inegration testing perspective, define a bunch of cucumber steps which will do the same `sign_in & sign_out` something that looks like `When /^I am signed in as  (\w*)$/ do end` and use that to do the actual navigation instead of using the rspec helpers provided by rspec.

*That should be good.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes Cucumber Stories for this case are the best, using the Javascript Scenario's we do also test Facebook Connect and other OAuth Services, work pretty well :)