# Testing redirect after login with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I've followed the recommendation from the Devise github pages for this:

http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Now this works great, but how would you test that you have this behavior now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there are two ways of testing it one in the unit level by writing tests in the controllers that inherit the application controller. The code will look something like

```
it "should redirect to page_x after logged in" do
  sign_in :user_role, @user 
  set_devise_mapping(:user_role) 
  get :new 
  response.should redirect_to(user_roles_dashboard_path) 
end
```

For cucumber you should probably write a step to do the login and assert if u are on the expected after sign_in page.

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024896/rails-devise-what-should-i-test-with-devise-and-rspec/4027270#4027270 for some more info on testing devise as such.

Comment: what controller test is that in?

Answer (score 3):

Hm... I think you should write own integration tests to check the behavior. No need of unit tests or functional tests if you did not mess with the Devise code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using mini test, it would be something like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  test "admins should be redirected to comments_url" do
    sign_in(users(:one))
    post user_session_url
    assert_redirected_to comments_url
  end

  test "No admins should be redirected to root_path" do
    sign_in(users(:two))
    post user_session_url
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
end
```